# Getting data from another Database within procedure in DB2

Tags: database, select, stored-procedures, db2

I have two databases DB1 and DB2 and I want to call a stored procedure in DB1 and get data from DB2.

```
 Create procedure diffdbtest()
 LANGUAGE SQL
 DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
 BEGIN
 DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
 SELECT * FROM Db2.myschema.tabletest;
 OPEN C1
 END@
```

I get Db2.myschema.tabletest is not defined.

Both DBs have the same user and password (if possible how can I use different users?)

Any idea what is wrong?

Running DB2 Express v10.5 Windows

Thanks.

Comment: Db2-Express supports Homogenous Federation (i.e. when both databases are in Db2-LUW).  Learn about federation in Db2 by studying the documentation. There is a learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

The only way as far as I know is you have to use federation. You need to:

create server wrapper to DB #2
create nickname on table that is referring the table tabletest
create user mapping 
etc.

Then, you can access that table via nickname.
Details on how to do this can be found in knowledge center: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.data.fluidquery.doc/topics/tlsdb201.html

Hope this helps.

Kevin See
Db2 Hybrid Cloud Security Dev Team

Comment: Was hoping for another answer :-) Thanks!